# Jenkins and provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, bash, build, jenkins

I'm trying to set my MAC to connect to Jenkins and be ready to build automatically. I've managed to create service that connects to Jenkins, but something is wrong.

This is my plist file:

```
<key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/my_scripts/run_jenkins.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/error.log</string>
```

this is my run_jenkins.sh:

```
cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/
sudo -u jenkins java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://secret.mission:8080/computer/ios-slave/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 841557ed7843ac76fe1618e375
```

**PROBLEM:**

```
 $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
     0 valid identities found
```

this happens when I try to build right after start-up. Of course after that build fails.

When I go `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` and then `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` the result is :

```
$ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
  [.. ]
     4 valid identities found
```

and build is succeeded.
Why is that MAC can't find those profiles when it runs from start-up and how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I've edited my plist file:

```
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>jenkins</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sudo</string>
        <string>-u</string>
        <string>jenkins</string>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/slave.jar</string>
        <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
        <string>http://secret.mission:8080/computer/ios-slave/slave-agent.jnlp
</string>
        <string>-secret</string>
        <string>841557ed7843ac76fe1618e375
</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/error.log</string>
```

and still same situation...

Answer (score 2):

Use the Xcode plugin and read it's documentation, especially this bit: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin#XcodePlugin-Signing